# What does it mean to quantize the lie algebra $su(1,1)$ into $U_q(su(1,1))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to understand the quantized version of $su(1,1)$, $U_q(su(1,1))$ but am having difficulty.  All of the material I could find online just jumps straight into the algebra relations.  So, in particular, what does it mean to 'quantize' an algebra.

Comment: That's an excellent question Bob which I asked many times before. You might be interested in this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289041/the-difference-between-q-deformations-and-h-deformations

Comment: If you would ask what it means to consider an $h$-deformation, the book Quantum groups by Kassel gives an explanation. $q$-deformations are still very mysterious to me as well.

Comment: Another thing I find very perplexing is how many people in the field casually say that the quantization procedure is essentially unique even when dealing with $q$-deformations. I have yet to find a proof of such a statement.

Comment: Anyway, if you are  looking for a intuitive way of understanding quantazations, the answer by Theo Johnson-Freyd here is an excellent read: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6200/what-is-quantization

Comment: @Mathematician42 Is it correct (but possibly simplistic) to say that you can quantize an algebra by adding sufficient structure to produce a Hopf Algebra?

Comment: Not really. Usually you start from a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. You can always consider the Universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$. This algebra is a Hopf algebra by declaring $\Delta(X)=X\otimes 1+1\otimes X$ for any $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ and extend $\Delta$ to all of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ as an algebra map. So even without quantizing you will get a Hopf algebra. This Hopf algebra is cocommutative though and is not what people would call a Quantum group. The quantized universal enveloping algebra $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ (as defined by Drinfeld-Jimbo) is non-cocommutative, thus a quantum group.

Comment: At least in physics applications, it can be anything in the  U() that a [sensible deforming functional yields](https://www.academia.edu/6176945/Deforming_maps_for_quantum_algebras). In practical applications, I have not stumbled onto fussbudgets protesting something is "not really" a quantum algebra, if it were useful. Specifically, by looking at the singular points of these maps you fashion representations with sizes and features not easily available for SU(2) or SU(1,1) ones, if the specific practical application requires it.   [Mini review](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/paradig.pdf).